# Calculating Grid Convergence for Lambert Conformal Conic

Tags: coordinate-system

What is the formula to calculate Grid Convergence angle (angle between true north and grid north) for Lambert Conformal Conic projection for a given location.

Searching online, I have been able to find the formula for calculating Grid Convergence for UTM grid only.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a paper [The State Plane Co-ordinate System][1], regarding Lambert’s Conformal Conic Projection:

> In order to obtain grid co-ordinates on a Lambert projection, we must
> remember that the grid co-ordinate system is a rectangular system,
> which is different to the ‘fan-shaped’ appearance of the projected
> region. So there will be a grid convergence factor to be allowed for
> when undertaking computations in grid-co-ordinates alone.
>
> The process
> is to convert the geographical co-ordinates to polar co-ordinates (r,
> θ), then convert these to rectangular grid co-ordinates. Consider the
> situation in the Northern Hemisphere, using the following diagram.

[image]

> Here we have also placed a false origin, so that all co-ordinates on
> the grid will be positive. As this is a simple additive (and
> arbitrary) transformation, we can leave it until the last step.
>
> In the diagram, r = radius of some parallel of latitude φ; r<sub>0</sub> = radius
> of the parallel, φ<sub>0</sub>, upon which the true origin of the co-ordinate
> system is situated; (x, y) are the grid co-ordinates of the
> geographical point (φ, ∆λ); θ = the projection angle for a departure
> of ∆λ from the central meridian, which has a longitude of λ<sub>0</sub>.

Note that the intermediate value θ of this geographic to rectangular conversion is exactly the convergence you seek.

θ = n ∆λ = n (λ – λ<sub>0</sub>)

[image]

It's worth reading the whole (short) paper for all the details:

"The State Plane Co-ordinate System" by Department of Civil and Environmental Engineering and Geodetic Science Geodetic and Geoinformation Science -- Section GS521 Geodetic Control Surveying]

Comment: Thank you for pointer @martin... In my case for Lambert Conformal Conic with one Standard Parallel, the formula is: sin(Standard Parallel) × (Longitude (of location) - Central Meridian)

Comment: @MartinF - the linked document does not exist anymore

Comment: This calculation gives you the convergence angle from the central meridian.  I assume this means the central meridian is aligned to true north?

Comment: @Rex: All meridians are aligned to true north-south.